# Matching Express Routes to Google Assistant intents

Tags: node.js, express, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have an Express app that I am trying to integrate with Google Assistant.

I've installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google and have followed https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0 which deploys functions to Firebase - however I would like to run them from a self-hosted Express server.

In my app.js I have set up as follows:

```
const {
  dialogflow,
  Image,
} = require('actions-on-google')

// Create an app instance

const gapp = dialogflow();
});
```

However I am unsure how to create the route that I add in Dialogflow console as the webhook - do I use the format below?

```
app.post('/webhook', function(req, res){
    gapp.intent('favorite color', (conv, {color}) => {
        const luckyNumber = color.length;
        // Respond with the user's lucky number and end the conversation.
        conv.close('Your lucky number is ' + luckyNumber);
    });
});
```

If so do all of my intents then go within this route?

EDIT
Updated in response to answer:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const {
  dialogflow,
  Image,
} = require('actions-on-google')

// Create a  google app instance

const gapp = dialogflow()

// Register handlers for Dialogflow intents

gapp.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Hi, how is it going?')
  conv.ask(`Here's a picture of a cat`)
  conv.ask(new Image({
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/imgs/160204193356-01-cat-500.jpg',
    alt: 'A cat',
  }))
})

// Intent in Dialogflow called `Goodbye`
gapp.intent('Goodbye', conv => {
  conv.close('See you later!')
})

gapp.intent('Default Fallback Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(`I didn't understand. Can you tell me something else?`)
})

app.post('/ga/webhook', gapp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define all of your `gapp` intents at the start of your Express server, then you can pass in your `gapp` object into the webhook that you define:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// ... gapp code here

const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json())
expressApp.post('/webhook', gapp)
expressApp.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, much appreciated.  I've modified my code and put it in the question above however my app crashes with an error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: No I'm not sure where in your code you're seeing an error. Certainly something is not being defined before you use it

Comment: Sorry, I realise that I am likely missing something pretty fundamental here.  All (I believe) of the relevant code for handling the request is in https://gist.github.com/jinky32/4bea02c1ecc48455808055a8ab1cb78d.  I assume that I am not handling the request properly but can't find an example of how it should be done.

Comment: The code looks right. In your error, there's often a stacktrace including the line of the error. That may be useful in diagnosing.

Comment: I'll mark this as the right answer.  One issue was that `const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json())` had to be defined before the `gapp` code.  As well as this there was some strangeness with Dialogflow intent names.

Comment: You can edit the code snippet if you have a specific fix